# My vuejs navigation guard not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs-routing, vue-auth

i am using vuex for statemanagement
this is my vuex code ,

here my logic is if token is exist in local storage then it will set isAuthenticated to true so it will be easy to check against routes.but some how its not working.

```
import axios from "axios";
import router from "../../router";

const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("tkn") || "",
  isAuth: false,
};

const getters = {
  isAuthenticated: (state) => !!state.token,
  authStatus: (state) => state.isAuth,
};

const actions = {
  login({ commit }, loginData) {
    // commit('auth_request')
    axios
      .post("/api/adminuser/auth/login", loginData)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        localStorage.setItem("tkn", resp.data.token);

        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = resp.data.token;

        commit("setToken", resp.data.token);

        router.push("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);

        commit("authError", err);
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
      });
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setToken: (state, token) => ((state.token = token), (state.isAuth = true)),
  authError: (state) => (state.isAuth = false),
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

and this is my router code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import auth from "../store/modules/auth.js";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/signin",
    name: "signin",
    component: () => import("../components/Authentication/Signin.vue"),
  },

  {
    path: "/",
    name: "dashboard",
    component: () => import("../components/Dashboard/Dashboard.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== "signin" && auth.getters.isAuthenticated == false)
    next({ name: "signin" });
  else next();
});


export default router;
```

currently if i do login still i can go to signin page and even i can goto dashboard without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a functions like below, in some file say helper.js and initialize it in main.js

helper.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
export function initialize(store, router) 
{  router.beforeEach((to,from,next)=>{ 
   const requiresAuth= to.matched.some(record=>record.meta.requiresAuth)
   const currentUser = store.state.isAuthenticated;
   if(requiresAuth && !currentUser){ next('/signin');} 
   else if(to.path=='/signin' && currentUser){ next('/')}
   else { next()}
  })
}
```

in your main.js

```
import {initialize} from './helper';
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
initialize(store, router);
```

Login page

```
methods: {
...mapActions(["login"]),
loginUser: function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       this.login({ email: this.email, password: this.password })
           .then(()=>{ this.$router.replace({name:'dashboard'})
                        //forward to this path after login
                     }).catch(()=>{console.log('login fail')   });
      }
},
```

Comment: i tried this steps and i got error whie pushing to dashboard
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/signin" to "/" via a navigation guard.
i am pushing to dashboard through action of vuex

Answer (score -1):

You should create store before you use

```
// auth.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from "../../router";

Vue.use(Vuex)
// ....
export default new Vuex.Store({
 state,
 getters,
 actions,
 mutations,
});
```

Otherwise the  `auth.getters.isAuthenticated` will be the function, not the vuex getters.

The vuex guide is here https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: my vuex is working properly,its problem related to my routing and authguard

Comment: You could `console.log(auth.getters.isAuthenticated) in the router.beforEach`

Comment: here what i am getting vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2181 TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined